# HttpException not caught by onError()

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, okhttp

I am making a request to a back-end server using Retrofit2 and RxJava2. When the response is 200 or 201 everything works fine. When the sever's response is 409 or 503 and a `HttpException` is thrown it is not caught by Observable's `onError()` and the app crashes.

The request that I am making is like this:

```
@POST("users/sign-up")
fun register(@Body register: RegisterBody): Observable<User>
```

The code snippet where I make the request is this (`applySchedulers()` only applies `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()`) :

```
api.register(body)
   .compose(applySchedulers())
   .subscribe(
        { user -> onNextRegister(user.id, email.toString(), password.toString()) },
        { error -> handleRegistrationError(error) })
```

The exception thrown is below:

```
 io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred.
 ComposedException 1 : retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 503 Unavailable
 ComposedException 2 : kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented
```

How can I prevent the app from crashing even if I implemented `onError()` for the Observable? Note that the code from `handleRegistrationError(error)` is still executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CompositeException` indicates that the actual issue is within `handleRegistrationError(error)`. Somehow you do something resulting in

```
kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented
```

Most likely it is related to a function you implemented as `TODO()`

```
fun TODO(): Nothing = throw NotImplementedError()
```

So just implement this (or remove the `TODO()`) and you might resolve your issue.

Comment: You're right. I'm new to Kotlin and didn't know that TODO might throw NotImplementedError. Thanks for your answer. Marked as accepted!